# How to get parent function to child function in php oop {$this doesn't work}

Tags: php, oop

I want father email to echo in child class function but it does not give any result yet. 
I think $this variable is the reason for this. 
I am not sure about it. 
Please tell me what is the solution and also explanation of child class priority from parent class will be very glad... Thanks in advance

I am new in OOP so I need your help.

```
class Father
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $email;

    function setInfo($fatherEmail)
    {
        $this->email    = $fatherEmail;
    }

    function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}

$info = new Father;
$info->setInfo('father@gmail.com');

class Child extends Father
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // here should be father@gmail.com (that is what I want)
        parent::getEmail();
    }

}

$child_info  =  new Child;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need that constructor. You also don't need to instantiate the base class. Look here:

```
<?php

class Father
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $email;

    function setEmail($fatherEmail)
    {
        $this->email    = $fatherEmail;
    }

    function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}



class Child extends Father
{

}

$child_info  =  new Child();
$child_info->setEmail('father@gmail.com');

echo $child_info->getEmail();
```

See it working here https://3v4l.org/CDfnM

Also consider declaring visibility of your functions, and privatising the properties:

```
class Father
{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $email;

    public function setEmail($fatherEmail)
    {
        $this->email    = $fatherEmail;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Having `private` vars means only that class can access it. Having `protected` vars and functions means that they are also accessible in child classes. `public` is available to all .

Comment: Thanks.. is there any way to get same output inside function just how i called?

Comment: I'm not following you, what do you mean?

Comment: normally when we call parent class function and this just echo a string its easily can be called in child class..so when parent function has $this and then child class does not react... see my comment line inside my child class function,please

Comment: but your constructor is useless and does nothing. You don't need it.

Comment: if i pass 2 peramiter extra in constructor and to join with gerEmail...inside constructor then?

Comment: You can either pass in the email in the constructor and inside that call  `$this->setEmail($email);`. Or, you can forget the constructor, and jusrt create `$child = new Child();` and then do `$child->setEmail($email);`